# Why do integers starting with 0 print out weirdly?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function in C (using Eclipse) which has a integer called `alpha`, and its assigned value is `077`.

But when I print it out, it prints `63` instead of `77` or `077`.

In fact, it's not just `077` but *any* integer with a leading `0` is printing an unexpected value. When I remove `0` from `077`, it *does* print the correct value `77`.

What effect does this leading `0` have?

Comment: I LOL'd out oud. (Yes, C combines the efficiency of assembly with the readability of... assembly.)

Comment: @jim: Please take a little time to emplace some _effort_ into your post. That means punctutation and capital letters. Thanks.

Comment: @jim: Also read [this](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't even know what I was doing. ;) (it was meant to be "loud", but I made a typo.)

Comment: @H2CO3: You laughed out loud out oud

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Exactly!

Comment: @H2CO3: :)) very funny!! keep laughing!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A number starting with a `0` is an octal number.

`077` is `7 x 8 + 7 == 63`

Comment: so is there other rules for other data types as well?

Comment: @jim C support decimal, octal and hexadecimal for integer constants. Octal constants are prefixed with a `0` and hexadecimal constants are prefixed with a `0x`. Decimal constants start with a non `0`.

Comment: @jim: This is _all_ covered in detail in your C book. Where is it?

Comment: @ouah: Thanks for your answer. After you replied i read about that. thanks again.